# How to turn off the screen saver of CentOS 7?

Tags: screensaver, centos-7

After a few minutes, the screen turns black and a screensaver will come out if I move the mouse, like on the screenshot below. How to turn all these off? The OS is Centos 7.

[image: screen]

Answer (score 39):

More detail:

- Click on the power icon in the upper left.
- Click on settings(wrench/screwdriver picture/icon).
- Click on the power icon.

Under power saving is the selection for blank screen, mine was set to a default of 5 min. I changed it to never.

Comment: This answer should get the credit. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

In your terminal write these commands:

```
xset s off
xset s noblank
```

**EDIT1:**

Try with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0.0
xset s off
xset s noblank
xset -dpms
```

Comment: I edit the post.

Answer (score 3):

In centos 7, click on your username in the upper right corner.  Then click 'Power' and change the time to what you want.  There is an option for 'Never' so that your screen will quit going black.

Comment: This is the exact same answer as https://superuser.com/a/1016299/245033, only less detailed.

Comment: @boardrider That answer is newer than this one.